# Use of undefined constant sql - assumed 'sql'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I'm new to PHP and just doing a test site for practice. I've run across the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant sql - assumed 'sql' in F:\wamp\www\css\Index.php on line 33
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  671872  {main}( )   ..\Index.php:0
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in F:\wamp\www\css\Index.php on line 35
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  671872  {main}( )   ..\Index.php:0
2   1.0141  680104  mysql_fetch_array ( )   ..\Index.php:35
```

Here's a snip of the portion that it finds erroneous:

```
30              <?php
31              
32                  $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";
33                  $query=mysql_query(sql);
34                  
35                  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
36              
37              ?>
38                  <tr>
39                      <td><?php echo $row['SKU'] ?></td>
40                      <td><?php echo $row['Product'] ?></td>
41                      <td><a href="#">Select Product</a></td>
42                  </tr>
43              <?php
44                  }
45              ?>
```

I've included the line numbers with the snip. The table that I'm trying to pull from is indeed "products," so I don't think that's the issue here. I've been scratching my head for the past hour or so trying to figure out where the issue is, but I can't figure it out. I guess I should take that as a warm welcome from Father PHP as an initiation rite of passage, huh?

Comment: The line mentioned by the error message is `$query=mysql_query(sql);`. And that's where you ought to look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `$` on line 33:

```
$query=mysql_query(sql); // Note that you have here "sql", not "$sql".
```

Instead, you should use:

```
$query=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast responses!

Answer (score 2):

Variables must begin with $

This is wrong-

```
$query=mysql_query(sql);
                   ^^^ This must be $sql
```

This should work -

```
$query=mysql_query($sql);
                   ^Added $
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it'd be something as simple as that. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @user3450245 Great! Glad to help! If the issue is resolved, kindly consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers.

Comment: Am I unable to accept them all? You guys all helped me so quickly. I don have the rep to upvote yet...